# How to select all the rows having same and latest value in a particular column from database mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select all the rows that are having the same and latest time in a particular column i.e., `time1`. The below image gives a brief idea about my question. Please guide me with this.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please provide data in text format,so that we can understand whats the problem.

Comment: you can use order by time desc

Comment: @ali_codex Thank you for your response, My table has 3 columns: id, name and time1. there are many records inserted with same name but different time and also there might be some rows having same time. So i want to fetch the records that are having same and latest time (in my table 12:30:30 is the latest time with 3 rows). I want that 3 rows as a output.

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A Thank you for your response, I have tried ORDER BY time1 DESC but its fetching all the rows from table. Is there any other way to fetch the rows with latest time from time1 column.

Comment: @sandeeppawar you have been answered by scaisEdge see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that relies on window function `RANK()`, available since MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, name, time1, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY time1 DESC) rnk FROM mytable) x
WHERE rnk = 1
```

The inner query assignes a rank to each record, sorted by descending time; top ties get the same rank, `1`. Then the outer query just filters in records having rank `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sunquery for max time

```
        select * from my_table  
        where time1  = (
          select max(time1)
          from my_table  
        )
```

Comment: Thank for your response, I have tried the above query it works fine for previous table. I have added one more table in below link how to write a query for displaying the red-marked rows.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzzVB.png

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,

```
select * from table1 where time1  =(select time1 from table1 order by time1 limit 0,1);
```

or

```
select * from table1 where time1  = ( select max(time1) from table1 )
```

or

```
 select * from table1 where time1=(select TOP 1 time1 from table1 order by time1 desc  )
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee28ced172c87bb5e8f8c66ea1dc3f31)

Comment: Thank for your response, I have tried the above query it works fine for previous table. I have added one more table in below link how to write a query for displaying the red-marked rows.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLkHo.png

Comment: @sandeeppawar  select * from t1   where time1  =(select time1 from t1 order by name desc,time1 limit 0,1)

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f3a840731922b2b506f9b6d72dddc41)